# Query array element and then field, from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have the following document in a collection:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("1123562e7c594c12942f"),
   "figures":[  
      {  
         "shape":"square",
         "color":"blue"
      },
      {  
         "shape":"triangle",
         "color":"black"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to make a query which selects the field `"shape"` from the second element of the array `"figures"`.

Using `db.test.find({}, {"figures": {$slice: [2, 1]}})` you can access the second element of `"figures"`, but can you also select **only** the field `"shape"` from there?

Comment: Using `.find()`? No. You can use the `.aggregate()` method. But it's better to do this client side.

Comment: the problem for me of doing it client side is that my actual array entries have fields which are *huge*, and that's why I don't want to query all the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query

```
db.test.find({}, {"figures": {$slice: [2, 1]}, "figures.shape": 1}).pretty();
```